# d3.js scale time on x axis not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to javascript and d3. I am using data from https://data.lacity.org/A-Prosperous-City/Los-Angeles-International-Airport-Passenger-Traffi/g3qu-7q2u to create a line chart visualization. Based on tutorials online, I have already set up y axis and calculated the data points for the line. Because there are a lot of dates in this dataset, I tried to just show years on x axis by parsing time. But nothing is shown on y axis. I think the problem came from`var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);`or`x.domain(d3.extent(DomesticCount, function(d) {return d.name;}));`, but I have no idea how those work.

Date format for ReportPeriod is 01/01/2006 12:00:00 AM. (dd/mm/yyyy)

Here is a screenshot of first few rows of the csv file:
[image]
Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 80
};

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', window.innerWidth)
    .attr('height', window.innerHeight);

var width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p");

var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);


var g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.name); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });

// read in our CSV file
d3.csv('Los_Angeles_International_Airport_-_Passenger_Traffic_By_Terminal.csv', function(data) {

    var DomesticCountMap = {};
    var InternationalCountMap = {};

    data.forEach(function(datum) {
 datum.ReportPeriod = parseTime(datum.ReportPeriod);
  
        if (DomesticCountMap[datum.ReportPeriod] === undefined) {
            DomesticCountMap[datum.ReportPeriod] = 0;
        }

        if (datum.Domestic_International === "Domestic"){DomesticCountMap[datum.ReportPeriod] += parseInt(datum.Passenger_Count);}
        
        if (InternationalCountMap[datum.ReportPeriod] === undefined) {
            InternationalCountMap[datum.ReportPeriod] = 0;
        }
        // aggregate into our map, using the terminal name as the map key
        if (datum.Domestic_International === "International"){InternationalCountMap[datum.ReportPeriod] += parseInt(datum.Passenger_Count);}
    });


    var DomesticCount = [];
    Object.keys(DomesticCountMap).forEach(function(mapKey) {
        DomesticCount.push({
            name: mapKey,
            count: DomesticCountMap[mapKey]
        });
    });
    
    x.domain(d3.extent(DomesticCount, function(d) {return d.name;}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(DomesticCount, function(d) {return d.count;})]);

    g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    g.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append('text')
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '0.71em')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
        .text('Passenger_Count');

    g.append('path')
 .datum(DomesticCount)
 .attr('fill', 'none')
 .attr('stroke', 'blue')
 .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
 .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
 .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
 .attr('d', line);

});
```

Comment: Can you please port few rows of the .csv file?

Comment: @nitte93user3232918 Sure. I have added a screenshot of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you assumed, the problem is not with your `xScale` function.
Instead, the problem lies at this snippet:

```
  DomesticCount.push({
        name: mapKey,
        count: DomesticCountMap[mapKey]
    });
```

When you are using `d3.scaleTime` it accepts the date object not a date string for your domain.

In the above code, `mapKey` is a `key` for object `DomesticCountMap`, this key is a string. 
As I mentioned `d3.scaleTime` takes a date object not a string. So, your this line `name: mapKey` make name value a `date` string.

Change `name: mapKey,` to `name: new Date(mapKey)` to convert it in date formate, and everything will work as you expected.

Here's is your working snippet. https://jsfiddle.net/g6kf99x7/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited as you suggested and the line is showing.